# Solving a system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have three differential equations that I'm trying to solve for but Mathematica keeps returning my input as the output without solving them. Why is it not solving the equations? Is there an error in my code?

```
Solution = DSolve[{n1'[t] == A21*n2[t] + (r*Exp[-((t - 2)/0.1)^2])*(n3[t] - n1[t]), 
n2'[t] == A32*n3[t] - A21*n2[t], n3'[t] == -A32* n3[t] - (r*Exp[-((t - 2)/0.1)^2]) (n3[t] - n1[t]),  
n1[0] == 100, n2[0] == 0, n3[0] == 0}, {n2[t], n1[t], n3[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Are you certain that there exists a closed-form solution for this system?

Comment: Maple fails with it.

Comment: `DSolve` returns unevaluated, when it cannot obtain a solution.  Provide values for the constants and rry `NDSolve.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)

```
eqns = {
   n1'[t] == A21*n2[t] + (r*Exp[-(10 (t - 2))^2])*(n3[t] - n1[t]), 
   n2'[t] == A32*n3[t] - A21*n2[t], 
   n3'[t] == -A32*n3[t] - (r*Exp[-(10 (t - 2))^2]) (n3[t] - n1[t]), 
   n1[0] == 100, n2[0] == 0, n3[0] == 0};

Solution = 
 ParametricNDSolve[eqns, {n2, n1, n3}, {t, 0, 10}, {A21, A32, r}]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   (#[A21, A32, r] /. Solution)[t] & /@
    {n1, n2, n3}], {t, 0, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{n1, n2, n3}, {.125, .5}]],
 {{A21, 0.25}, 0, 5, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{A32, 2.5}, 0, 5, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 5}, 0, 5, 0.1,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To plot one function against another use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[
   (#[A21, A32, r] /. Solution)[t] & /@ {n1, n2}],
  {t, 0, 10},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  WorkingPrecision -> 15,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
     {"n1(t)", "n2(t)"}),
  ColorFunction -> Function[{n1, n2, t},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][t]],
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 10}},
    LegendLabel -> Style["t", 14, Bold]],
  AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{A21, 0.25}, 0, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{A32, 2.5}, 0, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 5}, 0, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to plot n2-n1 of the solutions. How can I change your code to do this?

Comment: Can I use `parametric plot` to  plot (n2-n1) Vs time?So subtracting (n2-n1) I mean

Comment: Just use `Plot` and change the argument to `Evaluate[Subtract @@ ((#[A21, A32, r] /. Solution)[t] & /@ {n2, n1})]`